# not able to code cover in test class

Tags: unit-test

```
@isTest
public class testBilDrugExcutiondetail {

    static testmethod void testDrugExcutiondetail() {

        Account a=new Account();
        a.Name = 'sid';
        insert a;


        Order o = new Order(
          name = 'Test1',
          EffectiveDate = system.today(),
          AccountId = a.id,
          status='RFP Creation'
          );
        insert o;

        system.assertequals('RFP Creation',o.status);
        PageReference pageRef = Page.Bilcare_Drugs_Execution_Details;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
        ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(o);
        Bilcare_Drugs_Execution_Details d1= new Bilcare_Drugs_Execution_Details(sc);
        d1.Saveaction();

    } 
}
```

Comment: i am getting only 17% code coverage

Comment: You need to include the code that is being tested as well as the test class.

Answer (score 1):

A big part of the code is not executed by the Test class because in your Test Data there is no OrderItem records.

I recommend to you to insert some OrderItem records in order to improve code coverage in your test scenario.

You can add something like below (after inserting your order o):

```
OrderItem oi =  new OrderItem(orderId=:o.Id,Form__c='form'); (//you can specify values for other fields if needed);
insert oi;
```